# Unity: Triggering Parent Animation using OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, animator

this is my first time of positing on any forum, so here goes...

I am making my own Unity 2D game. However, I am really stumped with triggering an animation and I have been trying for a long time to try and resolve... if you're the person that can help then I would really appreciate it.

1 - I have a 2D collider on my aircraft carrier. See image 'Landing Carrier'.
2 - I have a script on this:

```
public class AirCraftCarrier : MonoBehaviour
{
Player player;
MoveLevel moveLevel;

void Start()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    //moveLevel = FindObjectOfType<MoveLevel>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision");
    player.LandJet();
}
}
```

3 - I have a player, which has a script and public method to either trigger my animation or set the bool to activate it in code:

```
public void LandJet()
{
    animator.SetBool("LandShip", true);
    //animator.SetTrigger("LandShip");
}
```

4 - The animator is attached to a parent object on the player. The Player script is attached to the child. Therefore, my logic is to get a reference like so, on my player script.
public Animator animator;

```
void Awake()
{
    animator = GetComponentInParent<Animator>();
}
```

Whatever I try to do it will NOT fire that damn animation. What am I doing wrong? It will print to the console, it will destroy the object if I want it... but no animation triggers.

To confirm, I have added the landing carrier's Box Collider 2D as the trigger. I've experimented with swapping these around but no joy.
See images. I would be really grateful for any advice.

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyHa8.png)

Other things tried:
I have tried swapping the triggers. I tried using animation .SetTrigger
I have tried using other game objects to trigger the animation.
I've rewritten the script a few times as well and searched online for a solution.

See screen shot of animation settings.

Not sure what other screen shots to include.

Maybe it is helpful to show the game object where the script is, see attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqGKH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMLe0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was in fact working, but Unity wasn't taking the updates. Upon restart the problem is resolved.